# External JSON data as linked server tables in SQLServer?

Tags: json, sql-server

A customer has a 3rd party product running on SQLServer (2016 IIRC). They have written a reporting stack using SQL queries against that system. Now they are thinking of moving to a new product that has a JSON-responding REST API and the data is hidden behind the API. I've been asked to explore how to handle reporting.

My first thought was to use SQLS as an interpreter for the API, adding a linked DB that makes their system look like a series of tables (the data is pretty simple). But looking over the JSON support in SQLS, every example I see is with the JSON text stored in SQLS tables, or using OPENROWSET to open an external JSON file. I do not see any way to make live queries with these systems - at lease no examples of this.

Is there a way to link SQLS to an external REST system for "live" queries?

Comment: This is a classic square peg in round hole problem. Getting SQL Server to fetch JSON remotely is possible, if you write custom CLR functions to encapsulate the data, but you'll have a hard time combining the data quickly and effectively -- something reports tend to rely on a lot. You will not be able to get SQL Server to translate a `WHERE` into an appropriate filter on the JSON API (if it has those); the closest thing to a standard for this is OData, but that's not particularly broadly suported.

Comment: You can look into periodically importing the JSON data into SQL, or rewriting the stack so it uses JSON exclusively (supplying JSON APIs over SQL is a much easier problem, since SQL Server can do most of the heavy lifting for you with `FOR JSON`), in preparation for moving to a new backend. Keeping SQL as the query language while "secretly" handling JSON in the background is theoretically possible, but almost certainly going to end in tears -- people expect things of relational tables that just aren't true for arbitrary JSON web feeds.

Comment: Ok, thanks everyone!